# Unexpected ';' for if ($firstPost && $numRows &gt; 1)

Tags: php

I get a unexpected error for ';' in my PHP code.

```
if ($firstPost && $numRows &gt; 1)
```

I tried removing the semicolon but I just got another error for unexpected '1'.

Comment: Are you kidding me ?

Comment: You seem like a learned man. How could you not think that it is an if statement and is comparing a variable to a number, and so it probably should have some kind of operator!

Answer (score 4):

`&gt;` is not valid PHP syntax. It should be `>`, as in

```
if ($firstPost && $numRows > 1)
```

`&gt;` is the HTML encoding for `>`. It looks like you copied this from a web page somewhere, perhaps while looking at the raw HTML. Be careful with that, as many symbols will be HTML-encoded and will therefore result in similar errors.

Answer (score 4):

`&gt;` is HTML encoding for `>`, that would make more sense in that context.

Try

`if ($firstPost && $numRows > 1)`

By the way, if something is HTML-encoding your PHP code, something went wrong in the process.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you were thinking. `&gt;` is probably only specific to HTML. You need to use a literal token `>` for greater than symbol.

```
if ($firstPost && $numRows > 1)
```